# How to automatically move my settings.toml to another format like .yaml when using dynaconf

Tags: python-3.x, django, configuration

I am using Dynaconf to manage configurations of my Django project.

Dynaconf sucessfully generated a settings.toml file with the current development environment.

I want to switch to using .yaml format that I read dynaconf supports.

Is there an automatic way to translate the settings.toml to an settings.yaml using dynaconf cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to use dynaconf to list the settings for all configurations defined in the `settings.toml` and export it to a `.yaml` file using the `-o filename` arguments of the `dynaconf list` command. As in:

```
$ dynaconf list -o settings.yaml
```